# Input Object into an array as a List in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner in Java. I want to get input from the user to a 2D array, and convert into a list of objects.

- When I hardcoded the data, it could be done as this way

  ```
  class Job // Job Class
  {
     public int taskID, deadline, profit;

     public Job(int taskID, int deadline, int profit) {
     this.taskID = taskID;
     this.deadline = deadline;
     this.profit = profit;
     }
  }

  public class JobSequencing{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // List of given jobs. Each job has an identifier, a deadline and profit associated with it

    List<Job> jobs = Arrays.asList(
          new Job(1, 9, 15), new Job(2, 2, 2),
          new Job(3, 5, 18), new Job(4, 7, 1),
          new Job(5, 4, 25), new Job(6, 2, 20),
          new Job(7, 5, 8), new Job(8, 7, 10),
          new Job(9, 4, 12), new Job(10, 3, 5)
    );
  }
  ```

but, I want to get this object arrays from the user input. When I am going to do this way, it was giving me an error.

- Code :

  ```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int count = scan.nextInt();

  int[][] arr = new int[count][3];

  for(int i =0; i<count;i++){
     String[] arrNums = scan.nextLine().split(" ");

     arr[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(arrNums[0]);
     arr[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(arrNums[1]);
     arr[i][2] = Integer.parseInt(arrNums[2]);
  }

  List<Job> jobs = Arrays.asList(
     for(int i=0 ; i< count ; i++){
        new Job(arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][2]);
     }    
  );
  ```
- Error :

  ```
  Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocationJava(1610612976)
  Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatementJava(1610612976)
  ```

Can you give me a solution for adding objects as a list from the 2D array that user inputs?

Comment: What do you expect this to do? `List<Job> jobs = Arrays.asList(
   for(int i=0 ; i< count ; i++){
      new Job(arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][2]);
   }    
);` You can't put a for loop inside a method call

Comment: I want to convert 2D array into a List.

Comment: It looks like you should first make an `ArrayList`, and then add `Job` objects to it as necessary, in a for loop *outside* the constructor or any other methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way also using `bufferedReader`,

```java
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
String x = bufferedReader.readLine();
String[] y;
int count = Integer.parseInt(x);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    y = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");
    jobs.add(new Job(
            Integer.parseInt(y[0]),
            Integer.parseInt(y[1]),
            Integer.parseInt(y[2])));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create List then in for-loop add to the List

```java
List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    jobs.add(new Job(arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][2]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
List<Job> jobs = Arrays.asList(
   for(int i=0 ; i< count ; i++){
      new Job(arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][2]);
   }    
);
```

try using lambda

```
List<Job> jobs = Arrays.stream(arr)
                .map(arrElement -> new Job(arrElement[0],arrElement[1],arrElement[2]))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```